# Angular / put reactive forms

Tags: angular

I want to edit my data in modal, with put method i am using reactive forms. first how can i open modal based on id of item?

**service.ts**

```
    public editCampaign(id){
    return this.http.put(this.API_SERVER + '/Campaign', id);
  }
```

**campaigns.html**

```
  <tr *ngFor="let item of campaigns">
<td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.createdAt | date }}</td>
      <td>{{item.status}}</td>
      <td class="icons">
          <button (click)="openEditDialog()">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
          </button>
        <button (click)="openDeleteDialog()">
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </td>

  </tr>
```

**campaigns.ts**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.campaignService.sendGetRequest()
    .subscribe((data: any[])=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.campaigns = data;
    })
  }


      openEditDialog() {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditComponent);
}
```

Second, how can i show data based on id of item?

**edit.component.html**

```
  <form [formGroup]="editForm" class="is-half" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Name</label>
      <div class="control">
        <input class="input"
        type="text"
        formControlName="Name"
        >
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Description</label>
      <div class="control">
        <textarea class="textarea"
        formControlName="SmsText"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
 <button mat-button class="primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

edit.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editForm = this.fb.group({
      Name: [''],
      SmsText: ['',  [Validators.required]],
    });

  onSubmit() {

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using the Angular Material Dialog? In that case please read the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component) especially the section about sharing data between the parent and the dialog.

> If you want to share data with your dialog, you can use the data option to pass
> information to the dialog component.
>
> ```js
> let dialogRef = dialog.open(YourDialog, {
>   data: { name: 'austin' },
> });
> ```
>
> To access the data in your dialog component, you have to use the MAT_DIALOG_DATA
> injection token:
>
> ```js
> import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
> import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'your-dialog',
>   template: 'passed in {{ data.name }}',
> })
> export class YourDialog {
>   constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: {name: string}) { }
> }
> ```

In your case you have two Options:

1. pass in the item id and get the data from the server
2. pass in the whole item and just use the data that is already there